# Merge column entries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

PeterM helped me with this question, but i dont want to create new one, thats why im editing this one.
I got another problem, sorry, im just new with sql.

This is my code that output all the information I need from the database.
What i want:
I created table with name "customers" with columns "id and customername".
Then i created simple script with INSERT INTO "customers", yes, its script like admin page.
The idea is: I want to add new orders from a separate page, for example: admin.php so I don't have to do it from a file.
How to easily do this?
I have admin.php file with: INSERT INTO customers (customername) VALUES (customername) and its working, i can add new order to database, when i fill html form, it doesn't show my new added order.

```
<?php
$output = "SELECT *, SUM(enddate - startdate) AS time FROM employees GROUP 
BY id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $output);
        WHILE ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $EMPLOYEE = $row['employee'];
            $CUSTOMER = $row['customername'];
            $WORKDATE = $row['workdate'];
            $WORKTYPE = $row['worktype'];
            $DAYHOURS = $row['startdate'];
            $ENDDATE = $row['enddate'];
            $TOTAL = $row['time'];
            echo "
                <tr>
                <td>$EMPLOYEE</td>
                <td>$CUSTOMER</td>
                <td>$WORKDATE</td>
                <td>$WORKTYPE</td>
                <td>$DAYHOURS</td>
                <td>$ENDDATE</td>
                <td>$TOTAL</td>
                </tr>";
        }

?>
```

My html form:

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-25'>
<label for='customers'>Choose OrderName</label>
</div>
<div class='col-75'>
<select name='customername'>
<?php
$customers = "SELECT customername FROM customers";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $customers);
WHILE ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$customer = $row['customername'];
echo "<option value=''>$customer</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check if "David" is exactly written in the same way for the two lines (no hidden characters or spaces ?)

Comment: Yes, there is no spaces/hidden characters. Yesterday i created two columns, one recording the start time and the other the end time (for example, in html form i insert: From 8, To 18), but I get the total (26), not the hours worked (10).

Comment: So, what is the result of the sql query : one line for David or two ?

Comment: When i created 2 columns, then show only 1 line for David (what i want), but without real worked hours, only sum of "From 08:00 To 18:00"..

Comment: Can you add a view of the content your table userworktime  ?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/owgkyv There is my language, but i think view is clear.

Comment: @doughtylatvia so basically what you want is the `sum` of `enddate` minus the `startdate` per `employee`?

Comment: @PeterM Yes. When I enter the start time (08:00) and the end time (18:00) on the form, it tells me: The employee worked 10 hours. And if I enter two identical employee names in the form, it shows me: The employee worked 20 hours, not the Employee worked 10 hours and again 10 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your query into something like this:

```
SELECT *, SUM(`enddate` - `startdate`) AS time FROM `employees` GROUP BY `employee`;
```

First you need to subtract the `startdate` from the `enddate` then get the sum of all the grouped results, hence the `SUM` part.

This should give you a result somewhat similar to this

**Results**:

```
| id | employee | startdate | enddate | time |
|----|----------|-----------|---------|------|
|  8 |    David |         8 |      22 |   17 |
```

The `time` column is the one you need.

I made a fiddle where you can see and test how it works, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40a959/5

Comment: I'm glad to have been of service.

Comment: Okay, i got another problem. Im trying to add all customers from my table under 1 drop down menu, but i get it out like this: Dropdown menu 1: Customer 1, Dropdown menu 2: Customer 2. What im doing wrong? Code: `<?php
$customers = "SELECT customername FROM customers GROUP BY id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $customers);
WHILE ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$customer = $row['customername'];
echo "<select name='customername'>
      <option value=''>$customer</option>";
echo "</select>";
}
?>`

Comment: Nevermind, I managed it by myself. Just </select> needed to be placed outside of echo: <.